# python msal account caching(empty cache)

Tags: python, azure, authentication

I am trying to use `acquire_token_interactive()` to obtain token and cache the account to use with `acquire_token_silent()`. But `get_accounts()` always returns empty list.

here is the code :

```py
import json
import msal

# Define the cache file path
MSAL_CACHE_FILE = ".msal_cache.json"

# Create a PublicClientApplication object with your app's client ID and tenant ID and set the token cache to the msal.cache.bin file
client_id = "your_client_id_here"
tenant_id = "your_tenant_id_here"
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)

# Define the scope you want to request access to
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

# Check if any accounts are already signed in
accounts = app.get_accounts()
if accounts:
    # If there are accounts, try to get a token silently for the first account
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=scopes, account=accounts[0])
    if not result:
        # If silent acquisition fails, prompt the user to sign in interactively with a domain hint
        result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scopes, account=accounts[0], prompt="select_account", domain_hint="your_domain_hint_here")

else:
    # If there are no accounts, prompt the user to sign in interactively with a domain hint
    result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scopes, prompt="select_account", domain_hint="your_domain_hint_here")

    # Cache the account for future use
    if "access_token" in result and "refresh_token" in result:
        cache.add({
            "client_id": client_id,
            "home_account_id": result.get("home_account_id"),
            "environment": authority,
            "realm": result.get("realm"),
            "local_account_id": result.get("local_account_id"),
            "username": result.get("id_token_claims").get("preferred_username"),
            "authority_type": "MSSTS",
            "access_token": result.get("access_token"),
            "id_token": result.get("id_token"),
            "refresh_token": result.get("refresh_token"),
            "expires_in": result.get("expires_in"),
            "extended_expires_in": result.get("extended_expires_in"),
            "token_type": "Bearer"
        })

# Use the access token to make API calls
if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    # (insert code here to make API calls using the access token)
else:
    print("Failed to acquire token silently or interactively")

# Serialize the cache to the cache file
with open(MSAL_CACHE_FILE, "w") as cache_file:
    cache_data = json.dumps(cache.serialize())
    cache_file.write(cache_data)
```

Comment: not sure whether it helps, but if you check the source code here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/msal/application.py and under get_accounts you may see in comment **This would also happen when the cache is empty**

Comment: I checked link, the reason is I need to load cached file before app requests https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache